# Elasticsearch Java API add direct generators to phrase suggester

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I was looking for an example to add direct generator to phrase suggester using elasticsearch java API. There are a lot of weired parameters when I'm creating DirecCandidateGenrator object. for example why should I give it a lucene IndexReader and how should I create it?

```
DirectCandidateGenerator(DirectSpellChecker spellchecker, String field, SuggestMode suggestMode, IndexReader reader, double nonErrorLikelihood, int numCandidates)

DirectCandidateGenerator(DirectSpellChecker spellchecker, String field, SuggestMode suggestMode, IndexReader reader, double nonErrorLikelihood,  int numCandidates, Analyzer preFilter, Analyzer postFilter, Terms terms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. You should use *DirectCandidateGeneratorBuilder* instead of *DirectCandidateGenerator*.